# Need help in converting 'while-do' block to 'awk' block for quicker processing

Tags: shell, date, awk, sh, julian-date

I need 7th field of a csv file converted from julian(yyddd or yyJJJ) to yyyymmdd. I have the below while do loop. I need the same logic using awk command for quicker processing. Can someone help ?

```
count=0
while read -r line1; do
        col_7=$( echo $line1 | cut -d ',' -f7 | cut -c4-6)
        year1=$( echo $line1 | cut -d ',' -f7 | cut -c2-3)
        echo $col_7
        col_1=$( echo $line1 | cut -d ',' -f1,2,3,4,5,6)
        col_8=$( echo $line1 | cut -d ',' -f8 )
        date7=$(date -d "01/01/${year1} +${col_7} days -1 day" +%Y%m%d)
        echo $date7
        echo $col_1,$date7,$col_8 >> ${t2}
        count=$[count+1]
done < ${t1}
```

**Input**

```
xx,x,x,xxx,xxxx,xxxxx,021276,x  
xx,x,x,xxx,xxxx,xxxxx,021275,x  
xx,x,x,xxx,xxxx,xxxxx,021275,x
```

**Output**

```
xx,x,x,xxx,xxxx,xxxxx,20211003,x  
xx,x,x,xxx,xxxx,xxxxx,20211002,x  
xx,x,x,xxx,xxxx,xxxxx,20211002,x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for `awk`. This requires **GNU** awk for its time functions. Tested it on terminal, so it is pretty much a one-liner command.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } { $7=strftime("%Y%m%d",mktime("20"substr($7,2,2)" 01 01 00 00 00")+(substr($7,4)*86400)-3600) } 1' filename.txt
```

Explanations:

- FS is field separator. Set it to ","
- OFS is output field separator. Set it to ","
- $7 is 7th field.
- strftime(format, timestamp) is a builtin function to format timestamp in seconds according to the specification in format.
- mktime(datespec) is a function to turn datespec into seconds. The format for datespec is `YYYY MM DD HH MM SS`.
- substr($7,2,2) is to get the two-digit year.
- substr($7,4) is to get the `day`. Because these functions take seconds as input, so a convertion to seconds is required.
- 86400 is 24(hours) * 60(minutes) * 60 (seconds)
- 36000 is a day. 60 (minutes) * 60 (seconds)
- 1 is for printing the input line. Doesn't have to be 1. Anything other than zero is fine. If you like RPGs,  you might want to change that to `999`.
- filename.txt is your input file.

Comment: Yessss. This works. Exact speed I was looking for. Almost 100000x times faster. Can you please explain the logic ? I am not familiar with awk concept

Comment: idk if  it matters but could could probably speed it up quite a bit by only calculating the gregorian date when the julian date changes (or hasn't been seen before if the dates aren't grouped in  the input), e.g. something like `$7!=prev{greg=strftime...; prev=$7} {$7=greg}` or `!($7 in gregs){gregs[$7]=strftime...} {$7=gregs[$7]}`

Comment: @EdMorton That's certainly would by caching the $7. But I'm pretty buzy right now at worldbuilding.stackexchange.com. I'm so sorry.

Comment: Its probably a bit late. But I just noticed a mistake there. It should've been 84600 (a day in seconds) instead of 3600. You know, math is hard.

Answer (score 3):

Just eliminating all the calls to `cut` will do wonders; you may not need `awk`.

```
count=0
while IFS=, read -r c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 col_8 rest; do
    col_7=${c7:3:3}
    year1=${c7:1:2}
    col_1=$c1$c2$c3$c4$c5$c6
    col_8=$c8
    date7=$(date -d "01/01/$year1 +$col_7 days - 1 day" +%Y%m%d)
    ...
    count=$((count+1))
done < "$t1"
```

Comment: This works faster, but I feel awk block will be even more faster. My input data is huge.